# Android : How to detect pinch in and pinch out?

Tags: android

I'm trying to detect pinch in and out using ScaleGestureDetector. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(mContext);
        final int minTouchDistance = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureListener());
        ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(mContext, new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                double scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                Log.d(TAG, "Scale gesture detected");
                if (1.0f > scaleFactor) {
                    Log.d("ScaleFactor", "Pinch Dection");
                } else  {
                    Log.d("onScaleEnd", "Zoom Dection");
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            }
        });
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int index = event.getActionIndex();
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
            Point p2;
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            //Rest of the code
             ......
     }
```

`GestureDetector` is working perfectly but pinching in and out is not getting detected by `ScaleGesureDetector`. Am I doing something wrong?  I want to detect pinch in and out gestures. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: try this library https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors

Comment: I just need to understand how gesture is detected. Using library for just 20 lines of code seems like an overkill. Thanks any way. If I can't figure out the problem I'll use the library.

Comment: You can have a look at the source code of that library to figure out it.

Comment: `but pinching in and out is not getting detected` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @pskink "when I drag 2 fingers toward each other or away from each other" just like you do while zooming in and zooming out on mobile.

Comment: return `true` from `onScaleBegin()`

Comment: @pskink Ok its working. Thanks a lot.